Device logging for AWS Cognito UserPool
I'm using AWS Cognito Userpool for user login in my app. And I use a custom auth flow with Lambda triggers: Define auth challenge, create auth challenge, verify auth challenge. Everytime an user log in, I want to log that event with the status of the login attempt(success or failed, or reset password request or logout), IP address, UserAgent to DynamoDB.
I've tried using CloudTrails but can't find a way to trigger Lambda to write DynamoDB or information about the login attempt. Please help my find a way to do this, thank you.
